# Is there a way to apply the FFmpeg "random" video filter to the audio too?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I've tried to search for a possible solution but all I found was [this now deleted question](https://superuser.com/questions/1603601/how-to-synchronise-audio-with-random-video-filter) (with no entries on the Wayback Wachine):

> The `ffmpeg` `random=` video filter shuffles frames randomly in chunks (or something along those lines, but the audio stays exactly the same (obviously, because it's only a video filter)
>
> What I want to know is, is it possible to synchronise the audio with its corresponding video "chunk"?
>
> If not, is there a way to just shuffle the audio randomly (ignoring the video) or shuffle both the video and audio at the same time?
>
> I'd rather not use another program like SoX, so was just wondering if it was possible directly through FFmpeg

Is it possible to apply or "synchronize" the frame-shuffling of the [random filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#random) to the audio with FFmpeg?

The random filter as-is is a video only filter and will throw errors if I try to apply it to the audio.

I would prefer for the solution to only use FFmpeg but if that's not possible or its much simpler to do with another CLI program that would be fine.

Comment: Sponsor author of "random" filter [Paul](https://ffmpeg.org/consulting.html) to make "arandom" filter and then use the same random seed.